# Can I have v-select in header of the v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any way to have v-select in the header of the v-data-table?

[image]

Here some image to illustrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `top` slot to inject your select :

```
   <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
  
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Standard"
        ></v-select>
      </template>

 </data-table>
```

Comment: Ohh I see, how many slot available for v-data-table?

Comment: this is the slots list https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots